# how can I pause my C program when a page of the console has been printed?

Tags: c, assembly, prompt, dump

I'm working on a basic SIC assembler and one of the features that I'm trying to implement is that during a dump function, if the program generates more than a page of text on the console, it would prompt the user to press a key before continuing.

My dump function reads out the hex values of a range of addresses in memory.

Comment: You have plenty of choice. For example a loop that continues until the user pressed a key, or use signals to handle that (with `wait();`), and so on...

Comment: On POSIX systems, the easiest way is to pipe its output through `more`.  Or on systems that have it, `less`.  e.g. `FILE *outfd = popen("less", "w");`.  i.e. let another program figure out terminal handling and all that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to define what a "page" is. Then you will know how many lines are available. Then when printing you stop to get input every X lines (where X is the number of lines per page) before continuing printing the next X lines.

Because reading input will block until the user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key (normally) then it will seem like your program pauses.

Comment: I looked more into it, and I discovered the ioctl() method and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

On POSIX systems, the easiest way is to pipe its output through `more`.  Or on systems that have it, `less`.

**`FILE *outfd = popen("less", "w");`** and use that instead of `stdout`.  [`popen(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) is specified by POSIX.  So is `more`, but you might want to try `less` first.  Or better, **use `getenv("PAGER")` before falling back to `more`**.

Let another program figure out terminal handling and all that instead of trying to roll your own.

Some non-POSIX systems, like Windows, also have pager programs you can use.  I think Windows even has a `more` program, but IDK if it has a `popen` function in any standard library outside of cygwin.

---

To redirect `stdout` to a pipe, you could use more low-level POSIX functions like `dup2` (search on SO for examples).

But I don't think you can do it mostly portably with just `popen`.  In the GNU C library (glibc), you can assign to `stdout`, e.g. `stdout = popen(...);`

But other C implementations may not support that: `stdout` can be a macro that doesn't support being assigned to.  ([See the glibc manual's Standard Streams page](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Standard-Streams.html).)